# Conditional rules for all columns of an attribute table in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

is it possible in the attribute table of a vector, to use a condition for the **whole** table in a single method?

I have computed a correlation matrix between all the fields and it could be very useful to highlight all the values, for example, > 0.8.

I tried to use the **Full row** option and to add `@value > 0.8` but it did not work..

Else I had to add a rule for each column and it could take a while..

Answer (score 2):

It wouldn't work if your equation included the '@value'. That should be substituted with the field use wish to calculate with.

```
"correlation matrix column name" > 0.8
```

**EDIT:**

OK so I've made a mock example from all the details you've given. I have a vector layer and a table fro the correlation matrix. I've joined the two together and applied full row conditional formatting across all columns for rows with a value greater than 0.8.  Is this what you're trying to achieve.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer. That's not what I am looking for. I already have the correlation matrix loaded in QGIS (as table) and I want to highlight all the values >0.8, but for all columns, not for a single column (or without having to add the same rule manually for all the columns)

Comment: Table names should be in double quotes - especially when there are spaces ;)

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is to make a custom expression function:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def any_value(feature, parent):
    for attr in feature.attributes():
        if attr > 0.8:
            return True
    return False
```

Use the Function Editor and create the function changing the `attr ==` line to match what you need.

You can then have a condition use this.

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't that be very fragile because it takes unrelated columns into account?

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. however I loaded your function and use it in the *Full Row* option.. but all the table is green now (I'm sure there are values <0.8 and also some strings)...

Comment: Post a screenshot of your data that might help